# Can't recover image from OpenCV DNN Blob using OpenCvSharp wrappers

Tags: c#, opencv, conv-neural-network, onnx

Using CvDnn in OpenCvSharp I'm able to load an ONNX network file and run inferences, but I can't do anything with the 4D data that results.

I use:

```
Mat inBlob = CvDnn.BlobFromImage(img, 1 / 256.0, sz, swapRB: true);
WriteLine($"Blob: {inBlob.Dims} - {inBlob.Size(0)}; {inBlob.Size(1)};
                  {inBlob.Size(2)}; {inBlob.Size(3)}");  // Shows "4 - 1; 1; H; W" as it should
```

to get the input blob. But I can't do anything with the input or inference result blob. For example, since MinMax won't run on 4D blobs, if I want the input range I need something like this:

```
Mat tmp = imageFromBlob(inBlob);
tmp.MinMaxLoc(out min, out max);
WriteLine($"Input blob range: {min} - {max}");
```

but all the methods I've tried for extracting a 2D Mat from the 4D blob have failed. Here are a few:

```
private Mat imageFromBlob(Mat blob)
{ // Produces 2D Mat, but any use throws protected mem exception
  // Mat img = new Mat(blob.Size(2), blob.Size(3), blob.Type(), blob.Ptr());

  // Exception: blob dims must be <= 2
  // Mat img = blob.Clone(new OpenCvSharp.Rect(0, 0, blob.Size(3), blob.Size(2)));

  // All the remaining techniques just return a new 4D Mat that I can't do anything with
  // Mat img = blob.SubMat(Range.All, Range.All);

  // Mat img = new Mat(blob.Size(3), blob.Size(2), blob.Type());
  // blob.CopyTo(img);

  // Mat img = blob.ExtractChannel(0);

  // Mat img = new Mat(blob, new Range(0, 1), new Range(0, 1), Range.All, Range.All);
  return img;
}
```

The 1st solution above is what I find in sample code, but there seems to be some bad pointer juju.
I guess I can use:

```
private Mat imageFromBlob(Mat blob)
{
  Mat img = new Mat(blob.Size(3), blob.Size(2), blob.Type());
  for (int y = 0; y < img.Rows; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < img.Cols; x++)
      img.At<float>(y, x) = blob.At<float>(0, 0, y, x);
  return img;
}
```

but YUCK.